# iOS: Create UIImage from the background thread?

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, uiimage

Apples documentation says:

> Because image objects are immutable, you cannot change their properties after creation. Most image properties are set automatically using metadata in the accompanying image file or image data. The immutable nature of image objects also means that they are safe to create and use from any thread.

[Link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed)

Also if you look at the answers of this ["Thread safety of UIImage"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645307/thread-safety-of-uiimage) question, it is concluded that it is safe to use them from any thread (at least since iOS 9).

**Yet**, there are comments that complain about issues, especially about creating UIImages on a background thread.

In my case I'm sure that this leads an issue where animations stop working.
Does anybody have insights on this?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ? UIImage can be created on any thread. UI updates must be done on main thread.

Comment: My animations stop being animated. Instead of smoothly transitioning from A to B, the views just jump.

Answer (score 4):

I can't see your code but I suspect this is a UIImage vs UIImageView issue if you're experiencing animation problems.

A [`UIImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview) *manages* image data off screen.

A [`UIImageView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage) *displays* your image on to your user interface.

Handling image data off the main thread with `UIImage` is fine.

Displaying or animating an image with `UIImageView` is not.